# Placing correctly formatted image behind a Hover Button CSS Animation

Tags: html, css, image, background, hover

I am currently trying to place an image behind a CSS Hover Animation I want to use with a Button.

The Finished product should look something like this:
[Mock Up of Finished Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpFwN.png)

Any help trying to properly insert and format a background such as this would be much appreciated, because I keep running into dead ends trying to insert an image.

So far this is what I have been working with.

```css
@import "bourbon";

* {
 -webkit-transition-property: all;
 -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(100,50,21,6);
 -moz-transition-property: all;
 -moz-transition-duration: .2s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(100,50,21,6);
}
h1{  font-family: calibri;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  background-color: #613f4d;
  padding-top: 70px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', calibri;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
}


.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 166px;
  height: 45px;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btn svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
}
.btn svg rect {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-dasharray: 422, 0;
  
  @include transition(all 1300ms $ease-out-expo);
}
.btn:hover svg rect {
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-dasharray: 10, 310;
  stroke-dashoffset: 33;
}

.btn:hover {
  color:#fff;
  font-size:18px;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<h1>Find out more about our</h1>
<div class="btn">
  <svg>
    <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="166" height="45"/>
  </svg>
 Company
</div>
```

Comment: Your requirement is to change the above snippet like the image which you have shared. Right?

Comment: @LibinCJacob Yes I want to place the above snippet on top of the image as shown in the mockup image I created.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting as shown here. Please check it.

```css
@import "bourbon";

* {
 -webkit-transition-property: all;
 -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(100,50,21,6);
 -moz-transition-property: all;
 -moz-transition-duration: .2s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(100,50,21,6);
}
h1{  font-family: calibri;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  background-color: #613f4d;
  padding-top: 70px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', calibri;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
}


.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 166px;
  height: 45px;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btn svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
}
.btn svg rect {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-dasharray: 422, 0;
  
  @include transition(all 1300ms $ease-out-expo);
}
.btn:hover svg rect {
  stroke-width: 0;
}

.btn:hover .heading {
display:none;
}

    
    .bg {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: .25s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.btn :hover ~ .bg {
  //background: #ff6d6d;
   background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpFwN.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<h1 class="heading">Find out more about our</h1>
<div class="btn">
  <svg>
    <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="166" height="45"/>
  </svg>
 <div class="heading"> Company</div>
 <div class="bg">
 </div>
</div>
```